# How to make 2 tables in different div columns and with different row height has the same table size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

so I have this 2 table to display on my web page inside a 2 column div using bootstrap.

- 1st table contains 4 column and has button in each row
- 2nd table contains data only.
- Each table can have maximum of 5 rows
- Each table has a background color of grey (#f5f5f5)

How can I make the 2 tables have the same box size(the grey background) if the other table has less than 5 entries (or even if they both have 5 entries since table 1 has larger row size because of the button) Is it even possible?

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h2>Table title 1</h2>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Column 1</td>
                        <td>Column 2</td>
                        <td>Column 3</td>
                        <td>Column 4</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Show full list</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <h2>Table title 2</h2>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Column 1</td>
                        <td>Column 2</td>
                        <td>Column 3</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Show full list</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the jsfiddle to reproduce my code..

https://jsfiddle.net/97jsnq31/

Comment: I have added code pls check i do not have jsfiddle account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the background-color from the table

Wrap the tables in a couple of `<div>` and make use of the css `flexbox` properties `stretch` and `grow`.

`stretch` ensures both containers are equal height

`grow` makes the table container (where the background color is applied) takes up all remaining space between the header and the button.

You might want to play around with some margin on the buttons to get white between the grey and buttons.

**style**

```
<style>
    .flex-row{
        display: flex;
        align-items: stretch;
        }
    .flex-col{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        }
    .flex-table{
        background: #f5f5f5;
        flex-grow: 1;
        }
</style>
```

**html**

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row flex-row">       // added class flex-row
    <div class="col-6 flex-col">   // added class flex-col
      <h2>Table title 1</h2>
      <div class="flex-table">     // added div with background color
        <table class="table">
        ...
        </table>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Show full list</button>
    </div>

  <div class="row flex-row">       // added class flex-row
    <div class="col-6 flex-col">   // added class flex-col
      <h2>Table title 2</h2>
      <div class="flex-table">     // added div
        <table class="table">
        ...
        </table>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Show full list</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

And a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ryw0spn5/)

A usefull link on understanding [flex boxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        .table {
            background-color: #f5f5f5 !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" height="100vh">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h2>Table title 1</h2>
            <table class="table" height="90%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Column 1</td>
                        <td>Column 2</td>
                        <td>Column 3</td>
                        <td>Column 4</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Show full list</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <h2>Table title 2</h2>
            <table class="table" height="90%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Column 1</td>
                        <td>Column 2</td>
                        <td>Column 3</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                        <td>Table data</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Show full list</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not sure if this is what you want

Comment: hmm..it is somehow weird looking..is it possible to retain the original row sizes but fill the void to make it look like the same box size??

Comment: @ErwinPlaza I just adjusted height; you can play around with it until you land at something you like

Comment: This is the actual result I wanted..https://jsfiddle.net/op37a9s1/2/ but using css only? is that possible?

Comment: @ErwinPlaza Might be possible but I am not an expert with css

Comment: You should add this part to question as well

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically change the height of the tables by calculating each table offset height and then adding the remaining offset height to the other table.

**Just select your table1 and table 2 and then call the function i created below.**

*you need to add the id to the tables before proceeding*

```
<script>
const t1 = document.getElementById("table1");
const t2 = document.getElementById("table2");

raiseTable(t1,t2);

function raiseTable(t1, t2) {
   if (t1.offsetHeight > t2.offsetHeight) {
        const td = document.querySelector(`#${t2.id} tbody tr:last-child td`)
        td.style.paddingBottom = (t1.offsetHeight - t2.offsetHeight + 11) + "px";
        return;
   }
   const td = document.querySelector(`#${t1.id} tbody tr:last-child td`)
   td.style.paddingBottom = (t2.offsetHeight - t1.offsetHeight + 11) + "px";
   return;
}
</script>
```

Here is the fiddle to check it out.
https://jsfiddle.net/op37a9s1/2/

Comment: I'm receiving Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of null using this code :/

Comment: Have you added the id to the tables?

Comment: id="table1" on one table and id="table2" on the other table

Comment: did you add the script on the bottom of the page? I will edit to add all of the code.

Comment: i sent the fiddle so you can check it out

Comment: this is the result I wanted! but is there any css only solution for this?

Comment: i am not sure,  i will look into that

Comment: I don't think you can dynamically do that through only css :/

Comment: This fails if the user resizes his browser. Never rely on javascript to resize elements if it can be avoided.